# Nifi: send file to HDFS; if fail, wait one second then retry

Tags: error-handling, expression, etl, apache-nifi

As part of my ETL process in Nifi, I need to send some files to HDFS. What is needed is to check if there's a failure. If so, it needs to wait one second then retry. If **that** fails it will again wait a second and retry. Finally, if that fails it will send an email to me and another admin. That last part is easy enough, I just have it going to a "PutEmail" processor. For the retries, I set it up as per this article: https://kisstechdocs.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/creating-a-limited-failure-loop-in-nifi/

However, it won't wait before each retry. I thought about adding an expression that is something like `${now():plus(1000)}` but it's expecting a boolean expression. Is there maybe a way to express the same idea in a boolean way? Or will I need to scrap this and find a different approach? Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ControlRate` for this, you can configure the throughput to be 1 flow file per second, or tweak the settings to allow multiple flow files through based on a grouping attribute, e.g. For example if you get 5 failed flowfiles in the queue at once, then it will take 5 seconds if you send 1 flow file per second "globally". If your use case says you just need each flow file to be delayed by 1 second (meaning after 1 second, all 5 flow files are sent), I believe you can set the properties to support that as well.

An alternate solution is a scripting processor, you could read in a (configurable) number of flow files at once, then delay one second, then transfer them all.